# How to merge multiple CSV files using Python Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, merge

I'm wondering how to merge multiple CSV files using Pandas, but using two specific criteria:

- I **don't** want values to be merged if they have a common key. As in, I **don't** want data to be merged as it would via a SQL Join. I want all raw data to show as it does in the original CSV file
- I want the CSV file values to be merged as new columns, and **not** as it does in the append function, where it puts the values underneath the first grouping

For example:

**CSV File 1**
`Column A    Column B    Column C
 100         200         300`

**CSV File 2**
`Column A    Column B    Column C
 400          500         600`

**Desired Output**
`Column A    Column B    Column C     Column A    Column B    Column C
 100         200         300          400         500         600`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [concatenate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) them column-wise by passing param `axis=1`:

```
In [26]:

pd.concat([df,df1],axis=1)
Out[26]:
   Column A  Column B  Column C  Column A  Column B  Column C
0       100       200       300       400       500       600
```